# Google chat API - sending message to direct in-line thread

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chat

Is it possible to send messages to specific google room threads using google chat API if Google changed the threading in rooms to with in-line threading?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Google Chat webhooks to place a message inside a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75832512/using-google-chat-webhooks-to-place-a-message-inside-a-thread)